# Handlebar template handling with numbers

Tags: handlebars.js, template-engine

I've a JSON string like

```
{
    "2013": [{
        "01": {.... },
        "01": {.....},
        "02": {.....}
    }]
}
```

I've a template like this

```
<script id="thumbnail" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#2013}}
        <div>Content</div>  
    {{/2013}}           
</script>
```

But this wouldn't work as the block to loop is like `{{#2013}}`. If I change it to some string, like `{{#thumbnails}}`, it works perfectly.

Is there a work around keeping the JSON as it is?

Comment: use #each method to iterate your data. example ul>
  {{#each 2013}}
  <li>{{agree_button}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>

Answer (score 0):

What about `#with` helper ?

```
<script id="thumbnail" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    {{#with 2013}}
    <div>Content</div>
    {{/with }}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var context = { "2013": [{ "01": "..", "01": "..", "02": ".." }] };
    var source = $("#thumbnail").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var html = template(context);
    $("#result").html(html);
</script>
```